# Use Storyboard Dynamic Prototypes TableViewCell for SearchDisplayController results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to use a Storyboard Prototype Cell to display content for search results using UISearchBar. My regular Prototype Cell (when NOT searching) appears fine, however, I get the following error when I search: the array I use to filter the results is being properly populated...

```
-[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:
my-App*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

**Creating the Cell**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) { 
        UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        name.text = @"test";
    } else {
       UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        if (_messages.count == 0)
            name.text = @"No Messages";
        else
            name.text = @"username";
    }


    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        return [_searchResults count];
    else {
            return _messages.count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did not work because table view cells are registered to a only for main table view. This will not work for your search results controller table view as storyboard will allowed to do that.

Use:

> [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

instead of

> cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Yes, you can register that class for your search table view,

> [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

but that will not have any of the stuff you designed in your custom cell in storyboard. You would have to create all programmatically.

Instead of this, you can create a nib file by copying current cell in to it. and register like this.

> ```
> [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"searchCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your nib file

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```